# Get accepted answer only

Tags: app

[image]

### About

Question stack is a simple web app that use stack overflow API. You can search for various answer, this app will find you an accepted answer from the list of thousands of answers

#### USE

[Link]>>> https://stackoverflow-8c7c2.web.app/  {[click here](https://stackoverflow-8c7c2.web.app/)}

#### Platform

WEB APP

### Contact

connect with me - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13829821/dev-skas)

### Code

Comment: "Verified" how exactly?

Comment: It would be nice if hitting _Enter_ in the search box would actually submit the query. The Twitter-like layout for the results seems suboptimal.

Comment: @tripleee it's just a first version, I will update this with new feature. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Still wondering what you mean by "verified". The terminology for the green checkmark is "accepted", not "verified"; but there is no guarantee that it is the best answer, or correct at all - it simply means that the person who asked the question decided to tick the box for some reason.

Comment: @tripleee when you search problem, you can find lots of question in stack overflow may be there is no accepted answer. I have just meant verified for accepted answer